# How to achieve recursion with int arrays as output? How can I achieve this by recursion below:

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

My stupid method is shown below:

```
    void StupidMethod(List<T> list0, int init = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list0.Count; i++)
        {
            List<T> list1 = GetChildList(list0);
            myIntArrayList.Add(new int[] { init });

            for (int j = 0; j < list1.Count; j++)
            {
                List<T> list2 = GetChildList(list1);
                myIntArrayList.Add(new int[] { init, i });

                for (...)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I would like to simplify it to something like that:

```
    void RecursiveMethod(List<T> list0, int init = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list0.Count; i++)
        {
            List<T> list1 = GetChildList(list0);
            myIntArrayList.Add(new int[] { init });

            RecursiveMethod(list1, i);
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to cope with the int array part:
`myIntArrayList.Add(new int[] { init });`
The length of the array is affected by the "recursive level?",  but I don't know how to get the "level". And the data added to the myIntArrayList is "stagger".
Don't know whether you understand.....
Anyone gets it and could lend me a hand? Or give me some possible hint or keyword about the "recursive level" so that I could search it on the internet.
Thanks!

It will turn really tidy if this is realized. I tried to add a global field "counter" to this but didn't find a proper place for it. Everytime the method run will increase the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the RecursiveMethod to include the recursive level and the current path as parameters.

```
  void RecursiveMethod(List<T> list0, int[] currentPath, int init = 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list0.Count; i++)
    {
        List<T> list1 = GetChildList(list0);
        int[] newPath = new int[currentPath.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(currentPath, newPath, currentPath.Length);
        newPath[currentPath.Length] = init;

        myIntArrayList.Add(newPath);

        RecursiveMethod(list1, newPath, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the help! That is exactly what I was confused. You really made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're trying to achieve, but will this "pseudo" work for you?

```
void RecursiveMethod(List<T> listOfLists, ArrayList arrayList, int init = 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfLists.Count; i++)
    {
        List<T> childList = GetChildList(listOfLists);
        var auxArrayList = new ArrayList(arrayList);
        auxArrayList.Add(init);
        arrayList.Add(auxArrayList.ToArray());
        Recur(childList, arrayList, i);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this method has no way to exit, so you need something like "if it's the last child, return all the info" and a way to track if arrayList is not null

Comment: Yes. Thanks for reminding me of the exit!